# Importxml from site using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, scrape

I am getting #N/A while retrieving price data from https://www.daraz.com.bd/.

My formula is

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/tresemme-shampoo-botanique-nourish-and-replenish-580ml-i2456416.html","/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/span")
```

What is the correct formula for price from importxml?
i want to get the listing price of different products on amazon and daraz. Other web scraping tools are paid and this formula is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Data on the [daraz page](https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/tresemme-shampoo-botanique-nourish-and-replenish-580ml-i2456416.html) gets loaded via javascript. So you'll need to use something like [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) that opens the page in chromium to scrape the things you want.

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // relative parts start
    let url = `https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/tresemme-shampoo-botanique-nourish-and-replenish-580ml-i2456416.html`

    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2",timeout: 70000});
    await page.waitForSelector('#container'); 

    let price = await page.$eval('.pdp-product-price > span', el => +el.textContent.replace('৳','').trim()); // remove ৳, and make integer 

    await browser.close();
    // relative parts end

    console.log(price);
})();
```

As for amazon, at my locale for any product to get the price you just need the following

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Hot-Wheels-HCK14-Culture-Ronin/dp/B0B2TRMYGQ", "concat(//span[@class='a-price-whole'],//span[@class='a-price-fraction'])")
```